# invoke a Tkinter class from another module

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a main file in which i have defined all the GUI of one application, and another module in which I have the m)ethods to import data to the Application.

When importing data sometimes there are duplicated records so I would like to let the user to decide which record to keep (first or last) by calling a Tkinter class stored in the main module.

## Main_App.py

```
class DialogDupli(tkSimpleDialog.Dialog):#dialog duplicated records

    def __init__(self, parent):


        Toplevel.__init__(self, parent)
        self.transient(parent)
        title="Delete duplicated records"
        if title:
            self.title(title)
        self.parent = parent

        self.result = None
        body = Frame(self)
        self.initial_focus = self.body(body)
        body.pack(padx=5, pady=5)
        self.buttonbox()
        self.grab_set()
        if not self.initial_focus:
            self.initial_focus = self
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.cancel)
        self.geometry("+%d+%d" % (parent.winfo_rootx()+50,
                                  parent.winfo_rooty()+50))
        self.initial_focus.focus_set()
        self.wait_window(self)

    def body(self, master):
        pdb.set_trace()
        self.selection = StringVar()

        self.radio=Radiobutton(master, text='Keep First record', variable=self.selection, value='First',state='active').grid(row=0,column=0,sticky=W)
        self.radio=Radiobutton(master, text='Keep Last record', variable=self.selection, value='Last',state='active').grid(row=1,column=0,sticky=W)


    def apply(self):
        cri = self.selection.get()
        self.result = cri
root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

## import.py

```
from Main_App import DialogDupli
```

...#bla bla bla then method to import data

#Once my dataframe is created I check if there are duplicate records in the time stamp

```
    dupli=df.reset_index().duplicated(subset=df.index.names)
    if dupli.any():#there are duplicates
        tkMessageBox.showwarning("Duplicated records","There are duplicated records in the Time Stamp")
        dialog=DialogDupli(root)#here call to the GUI in Main_App.py
```

Now the problem is how to call the argument root from my import module as it is not recognised.

```
name 'root' is not defined
```

I checked similar questions here an another websites but still unclear for me.

Answer (score 3):

You have to change import or definition of root, because the root argument is defined outside the class.

You should paste it into your Main_app.py

```
root = tk.Tk() 
app = DialogDupli(parent=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Here you have example:
https://github.com/piotrowy/steganography_chat/blob/master/client/client.py
https://github.com/piotrowy/steganography_chat/blob/master/client/view.py